# Git push changes from 1 remote to another

Tags: git

So I have 2 repos right now, `A:B` where A is the remote origin name, B is the branch name, and `C:D` where C is the second remote origin name, D is the branch name.

I do work on `A:B`, so that includes PRs, etc. Once the work is done, `A:B` will contain the latest version of the code I want. Now I want to push the changes from `A:B` to `C:D`. Is this how I would do it?

```
git remote add crepo C_GIT_URL
git push crepo B:D
```

Would that push all the changes from B branch in A repo to D branch in C repo?

Comment: Side note: you don't push *changes*, you push *commits*. (Git only stores snapshots, i.e., commits. *Changes* arise by comparing one commit to another.) Other than that, as Ben already answered, everything is fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is written, yes that will do what you expect.

To reiterate:
`git push <remote> B:D` will update the `<remote>` branch `D` with the changes made to the *local* branch `B`